# What Happens If You delete Smash 4 3DS Update Data?

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds, super-smash-bros-4

I am currently playing Super Smash Bros for 3DS on a normal 3DS system and the game is on version 1.0.4. I bought it on the e-Shop. I want to update it to the newest version (Mewtwo, Lucas, Ryu etc.) but I don't have enough blocks left, where the game took up 10,000 blocks and I only have a 2GB SD card.

I could do a transfer, but I want a easier way. I have nothing else I can delete to get more SD card space, but if I delete the current update data for Smash, I would have enough to update to the newest version (1,500 blocks needed). If I delete this, will all my save data go down with it?

Answer (score 3):

No, it will keep your save data, you can safely delete the current version then download the update.

Comment: why is this downvoted?

Answer (score 1):

I've had a similar case a couple of times when I wanted to play with a friend who forgot to update his Game. You can safely delete the update on both consoles and it will create a new temporary save. The only down-side is you won't have everything unlocked while playing without the update and ofcourse the balancing patches aren't in there. After you are done playing you can download the update again and use the regular save you had used before.

It is also possible if you for example need to download 1000 blocks but only have 500 free blocks at the Moment and 2000 blocks are already used by an old update. Another friend always needed to delete his old update before he could download the new one because his SD-Card didn't have enough free memory. In the long-term he still needed to invest in a new SD-Card though because all the DLC-Characters used up quite a lot of space.